# Why does my program pause after using scanf?

Tags: c, cmd, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *userInput;
    userInput = (char*)malloc(sizeof(userInput));

    printf("Commands:\n");
    printf("\ta name - adds given name to list\n");
    printf("\tr name - removes given name from list\n");
    printf("\tp      - prints out list\n");
    printf("\te      - exits\n");

    printf("\n\nEnter a command: ");
    scanf("%s\n",userInput);
    printf("\nThe user input was: %s\n", userInput);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile the code "gcc -std=gnu99 -m32 -Wall -g -o namelist namelist.c" 
whenever I run the executable all of the first printf are displayed and I get prompt on an input. Whenever I enter an input and press enter, I don't get prompt the next printf until I put another input in.

[image: This is what is looks like when I run the program]

Comment: Use the `gdb`  debugger to run your program step by step.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Hint: `\n` is for carriage return. Do you see any `\n` in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm ?

Comment: Read documentation of [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html)

Comment: You probably want to use [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD, a program that copies files and starts other programs. You are using a console like CMD also uses a console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take out the "\n" in your

```
scanf("%s\n",userInput)
```

Comment: Omg thank you very much this was driving me crazy

Comment: You then have a buffer overflow for any input of more than 4 bytes, e.g. `foobar`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I believe, buffer overflow occurs for input more than 3 characters (last character for `\0`).  This: `malloc(sizeof(char *)) - 1` to be exact.

Answer (score 1):

While a character (`char`) or set of characters (`char*`) are coming from `stdin` with `scanf` of similar function `\n` (result of Enter key pushing) remains in the buffer. So before next input the program should clean that `\n` as well as all other mess that can be in the input buffer (e.g. after incorrect  entering numbers, such as `12asw` - `scanf` takes `12` and leaves `asw\n` in the buffer).

Consider the following example and pay attention, that I recommend to use `clnInpBuf()`:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

void clnInpBuf()
{
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[10];
    char ch;
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    fflush(stdin); // in some cases that works for input stream 
                   // (but fflush is better to use only for output streams)
    scanf("%9s", str);
    clnInpBuf(); // this works always
    printf("char was %c.\n", ch);
    printf("string was %s.\n", str);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

template for your "command processor" can be:

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    char name[21];
    char command;
    while (1)
    {
        scanf("%c", &command);
        clnInpBuf();
        switch (command)
        {
        case 'a':
        case 'r': scanf("%20s", name);
                  clnInpBuf();
                  printf("Command was:\n%c %s\n", command, name); // if ('a'==command) addRecord(name); else removeRecord(name);
                  break;
        case 'p': // TODO: add output
                  break;
        case 'e': return 0;
                  break; // this is not realy needed
        default:
                  printf("Wrong command\n");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is *wrong*, you can only `fflush` an *output stream* or `NULL`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, you are right!!... But I actually wrote "in some cases that (fflush) works" and "I recommend to use clnInpBuf()"

Answer (score 0):

Read *carefully* [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). Notice that with `gcc -m32` you have `sizeof(userInput)` equal to 4 (the size of all pointers is the same; without the `-m32` it would be 8). So if the user is typing something like `working` (or any input of four characters or more, not just one letter like `a`), you have [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (because of a [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)) and that is really [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). You probably should consider using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) instead (or perhaps even [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)), e.g.

```
char* userInput=NULL;
size_t sizeInput= 0;
printf("Commands:\n");
/// put your other printfs here, then
ssize_t lengthInput = getline(&userInput, &sizeInput, stdin);
if (lengthInput < 0 || userInput==NULL)
  { perror("input error"); exit(EXIT_NULL); };
```

Now you have the entire typed line in `userInput` (including the terminating newline) and you know that its length is `lengthInput`. You can [*parse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) that line, perhaps using [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) (hint: use its return count, and consider using `%n`) or just using other techniques (some `strcmp`, or [strtok(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html)...). When done, you should `free(userInput)`.

Notice that `scanf` (or `sscanf`) do not allocate any memory for parsed data, unless you use `%ms` (which is probably POSIX specific). With `%s` it always expecting some fixed length buffer, and for a *array* buffer declared `char buf[64];` you'll better give the size with `%63s`; BTW, you should always test the result count of `scanf`. So you might code (after the above)

```
char nambuf[64];
if (sscanf(userInput, "a %63s", nambuf)==1) {
 // use nambuf to add it
}
else if (sscanf(userInput, "r %63s", nambuf)==1) {
 // use nambuf to remove it
}
```

(but the above is a bit silly, we read an arbitrary sized line but process `nambuf` of at most 63 bytes). You could just use `scanf` like `if (scanf("a %63s", nambuf)==1)` without needing any `userInput`.

Alternatively, you could use the Linux specific `%as` or better the POSIX specific `%ms` like:

```
char* nameptr=NULL;
if (scanf("a %ms", &nameptr)==1) {
```

then that successful `scanf` would have `malloc`-ed and filled `nameptr` and you should later `free(nameptr)`. If you want to accept only lowercase letters consider coding something like `if (scanf("a %m[a-z]", &nameptr)==1)` etc...

Answer (score 0):

This statement will allocte 4 bytes of data as userinput is pointer.
    userInput = (char*)malloc(sizeof(userInput));

as pointed by the above answer this will cause a buffer overflow when the string size is more than 3 bytes.

also i would suggest fgets() over scanf when reading a string

sample code -

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>


   int main() {
      // your code goes here
     char *userinput = (char *)malloc(100);
     fgets(userinput,100,stdin);
     printf("%s",userinput);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only additional information you are giving is the suggestion to use `fgets`. But then you need to give more code.

Comment: added a sample code for fgets